# In sapper/svelt is there a shortcut to components

Tags: svelte, sapper

In nuxts/vue there is an alias @ and ~ to mean the root of the app. is there something similar in sapper/svelte to that in a deep route like /very/deep/page/1/2/3/4 I don't have to do something like:

```
import Head from '../../../../../../../../components/Thingy.svelte'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using rollup, you can obtain it using [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias).

For example, in your `rollup.config.js`:

```js
// ...
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import path from 'path';
// ...

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    alias({
      resolve: ['.jsx', '.js', '.svelte'], // optional, by default this will just look for .js files or folders
      entries: [
        { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') },
      ]
    }),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Then `@` will be an alias for the `src` directory under your toplevel.

If you are using webpack instead, you can use the [resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) config property. For example, inn your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
// ...
import path from 'path';
// ...

module.exports = {
  // ...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  }

  // ...
};
```

Comment: This works very well, but can I just add that for sapper, you need to add the alias config to both the client and server bits of the rollup config.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in a directory like `src/node_modules/components`, and then you'll be able to import them like `import Foo from 'components/Foo.svelte'`. Just make sure that directory isn't gitignored!

Comment: I think this should work, but I would be disinclined to add local stuff to node_modules as it may well be ignored by .gitignore files.

Comment: that's why I said "Just make sure that directory isn't gitignored" :) All you need to do is add `!src/node_modules`

Comment: Thanks! So svelte way, love it :)

Comment: Hahaha this is such a ridiculous solution, I cannot believe the author of the framework just suggested putting application data inside node_modules

Comment: This could maybe work, but sounds like a very bad idea. The solution by @Marco Pantaleoni works, just remember to add the alias to both the server and client of rollup config